# How to use a Raycast with a layer while standing inside a trigger?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a large transparent cube object that has a box collider with trigger ON, and I am able to walk through it. That object has a specific layer attached to it called “transparentMask”.

What I have been trying to do is, while I am inside that object, if the Raycast below detects that specific layer, then I am able to perform a specific movement.

The problem is that while I am inside the cube, the Raycast doesn’t cast/activate. Only when I am standing in front of the object at a distance up to `2f` does the Raycast begin to work, but then the second I step forward and enter the trigger, the Raycast stops. I made sure that while in the cube, the Raycast is only casting inside the cube and not beyond it and still nothing. Is there a way around this?

```
void Update()
{
    int transparentMask = 1 << 8; 
   
    if (isWalkingInCube)
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, 2f, transparentMask))
        {
            // Do a movement
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html):

> Notes: Raycasts will not detect Colliders for which the Raycast origin
> is inside the Collider. [...]

This means that rays originating from inside the cube will not detect hits on that same cube.

One easy way to get around this (depending on the situation) is to simply reverse your raycast.

Another way is to enable *Queries hit backfaces* in the Physics settings. Be careful with this because it might change the behaviour of other systems in your project.

Comment: That quote from the docs is a bit confusing. I have code where I can float up to the top of the cube while standing in it by holding down spacebar. The origin of my Raycast is above the collider, while my player is inside the trigger, so shouldn't that work? This is how it looks like: https://ibb.co/x5KQFQc so my Raycast is clearly above the entire cube object but it still won't work.

Comment: Please explain. What doesn't work? The hit? I assume the script is on your player. In this picture, the ray doesn't hit the cube at all. So it seems clear that there is no raycast hit in this situation. Regarding the quote: It means that if your ray origin is inside the cube, it will not detect hits on the cube.

Comment: Yeah when I add `Debug.Log()` just after the `if (Physics.Raycast)` line (to see if there was a hit) nothing happens. This happens when I use `!` aswell, and also when I change the direction from `transform.forward` to `-transform.forward` or even `Vector3.up`.

Comment: If it does not fire regardless of `!` or not, then `isWalkingInCube` must be `false`. To reverse the `Raycast`, in addition to flipping the direction, the origin must also be changed to the former target point. Please provide a little more information in your question to get a clear idea of the intention and the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: The only thing that matters is where you ray begins (it must begin outside of the trigger) and it must hit the surface from the outside inwards.  In other words - the ray must begin outside and end inside a collider.